# Why is the SSH server not working on Android 4, are the ports being blocked?

Tags: ssh, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am having difficulty ssh'ing into my new Android 4 (Samsung Nexus) phone.

I have installed various SSH Servers but in in all cases the ssh connection just hangs (i.e. I don't get as far as username/password).

As an example, using SSHDroid:

Verbose SSH log from my linux box :

```
joel@pepper ~ $ ssh  -p 2222 root@192.168.1.65 -vvv
OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.65 [192.168.1.65] port 2222.
```

The output from nmap does not look right. A status of filtered on the port implies a firewall is blocking it:

```
joel@pepper ~ $ sudo nmap -sS  192.168.1.65 

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-11-20 21:29 GMT
Nmap scan report for android-63731d6ebec9e01.lan (192.168.1.65)
Host is up (0.019s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
2222/tcp filtered unknown
MAC Address: A0:0B:BA:B4:5F:59 (Unknown)
```

Comment: This really locks like blocked ports. You could also try a ping, followed by an `telnet <ip> <ssh_port>` and you could confirm that the socket is opened on OS level via `netstat -ltnp`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the default ssh port *IS* 22 on Ubuntu, just as "Lie Ryan" pointed out.  You might want to check your `sshd_config` files on your PC, if you want to take a look at [this](http://techie-buzz.com/foss/change-default-ssh-port-in-linux.html) article, it specifies on how to change the default ssh configuration on Ubuntu--as well as the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html).  Beyond that, check your current firewall settings, you might be able to open that specific port temporarily to ssh-type service if you want to confirm that it's not something else.

Aside from that, it seems to me that this question was asked more than 6 months ago; if the OP hasn't figured it out by now, I doubt he'll be interested to pursue it further.  I suggest either accept an answer, provide update on the situation since, or perhaps close the question.

EDIT: depending on your android ssh-server app, and whether or not you're running it with su privileges, this is from the "QuickSSHD" website:

> non-root users are limited to ports < 1024 and the QuickSSHd application user, which CAN read and write to the SD Card.

Comment: Don't you mean `> 1024`?

Comment: that is the exact thing that's on the website...copied and pasted. [Here](http://teslacoilsw.com/quicksshd) you go, take a look for yourself

Comment: That's probably a typo. Generally ports `< 1024` are reserved to root user, and other ports can be accessed by anyone. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16564/why-are-the-first-1024-ports-restricted-to-the-root-user-only

Comment: I don't know...but, as I said, generally there's a reason why most android-based SSH-servers require root permission; and if the OP is having trouble accessing it from PC, it may explain it, since SSHDroid and QuickSSHD are very [similar](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=10775923&postcount=5) and based on the same "core parts"

Comment: Oh sure, I'm just talking about communicating on ports in question. I know that `SSHD` on android runs on 2222, usually.

Comment: yea, as I said, it's been a number of months now since the OP; If he hasn't at least tried to switch APPs, or found out more on his own, chances are he wouldn't care to find out now either...so, I'm not sure where this question stands as of now, but I would look into closing it if there are no updates from the OP on the matter.

Comment: also...check out the line that starts with `debug2` in the first log output: `ssh_connect: needpriv 0` ; isn't "zero" the uid for the root user on android? Based on that as well, I would say that the SSHD app DOES need a rooted device with su privileges during initiation for port 2222 as suggested by the ["QuickSSHD"](http://teslacoilsw.com/quicksshd) website.  Or he could try connecting to port 22 from Ubuntu as root user.

Answer (score -1):

The default ssh port is 22 not 2222, perhaps that's the root cause of the issue? Try connecting on port 22.

Comment: Actually, all the SSH servers on the market that I know of use the port 2222.

Comment: Ports below 1024 are only available to root users on Linux, that's why SSH servers on Android don't use port 22 as the default.